# How to style the selector of a RadDataForm ListPicker

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm having a RadDataForm in a Nativescript-Angular App.

This RadDataForm shows a Listpicker for one of my properties.

I have read about styling the components of a RadDataForm but it's missing the part about how to style the "wheel texts" that are shown when I change the date. (Or am I missing something?)

They stay black but I need them in another color (i.e. white)

I already solved this for the DatePicker but that does not work for Listpicker "correctly" --> It is changing color after I change selection.

I have a [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Nj15Dj&v=6) setup and testing it with an iOS Device.

Comment: ListPicker operates differently, the color should be set in the delegate implementation. As the native component is not open source, it's unclear how it should be implemented.

Comment: So this leads myself to the conclusion that a "dark theme (black background)" is not possible for those Listpickers due to the fact that I can't change the font color!?

Comment: I figured out how to change the color with a delegate. Problem now is I can't select anything...

Comment: Of course if you override the delegate with your own, you might loose whats there by default that handles selection. You might have to take this to ui feedback repo and ask for help.

Comment: Found the solution with the help of the Nativescript-Example App.
https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-example-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around a lot I found the [Nativescript-Example App](https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-example-application).

Inside this App there is also a RadDataForm with a Listpicker that is styled.
The App also shows the used code for the example.

Inside my component I have:

```
onEditorSetup(event: DataFormEventData) {

    const property = this.myDataForm.dataForm.getPropertyByName(event.propertyName);
    const t = property.editor.type;
    if (t === DataFormEditorType.Picker) {
        console.log("found picker editor for " + property.displayName);
        if (app.ios) {
            this.setupPickerViewEditor(event);
        }
    }
}

setupPickerViewEditor(event: DataFormEventData) {
        console.log("setting up editor: " + event.editor);
        const delegate = UIPickerViewDelegateImplementation.new().initWithOwner(event.editor);
        this.delegates.set(event.propertyName, delegate); // storing the delegate cause they are weak references.
        event.editor.pickerView.delegate = delegate;
    }
```

My Implementation for the picker delegate that has a white text is:

```
export class UIPickerViewDelegateImplementation extends NSObject implements UIPickerViewDelegate {

    static ObjCProtocols = [UIPickerViewDelegate];
    static new(): UIPickerViewDelegateImplementation {
        return <UIPickerViewDelegateImplementation> super.new();
    }

    private _owner: any; // TKDataFormPickerViewEditor

    initWithOwner(owner: any /* TKDataFormPickerViewEditor */): UIPickerViewDelegateImplementation {
        this._owner = owner;

        return this;
    }

    pickerViewTitleForRowForComponent(pickerView: UIPickerView, row: number, component: number): string {
        return this._owner.options[row];
    }

    pickerViewDidSelectRowInComponent(pickerView: UIPickerView, row: number, component: number): void {
        this._owner.selectedIndex = row;
        this._owner.owner.editorValueChanged(this._owner);
    }

    pickerViewAttributedTitleForRowForComponent(pickerView: UIPickerView, row: number, component: number): NSAttributedString {
        const title = this.pickerViewTitleForRowForComponent(pickerView, row, component);
        const attr = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObjectForKey(UIColor.whiteColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName);
        const res = NSAttributedString.alloc().initWithStringAttributes(title, attr);

        return res;
    }
}
```